# How to open Compose Mail(New Mail) Screen using Apple Script with Attachement At the specified position?

Tags: applescript

I have an apple script that opens the compose mail(new mail) screen with attachment at the last of the message.

But I want a apple script that places the attachment at user specified position.I did a lot of google search but didn't found anything. Please give me some solution.

Message Body Template is below:

> Dear Name,
>
> --------Some Text----------
>
> --------Some Text-----------
>
> Attachment 1 is below:
>
> Here attachment 1 should appear
>
> Attachment 2 is below:
>
> Here attachment 2 should appear
>
> --------Some Text----------
>
> --------Some Text-----------

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example :  two attachments are inserted after the third paragraph

```
set newOutgoingMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:"test", content:someText}
tell newOutgoingMessage
    make new paragraph with data (" " & return & return & return) at after paragraph 3 of content
    make new attachment with properties {file name:filePath1} at after paragraph 4 of content
    make new attachment with properties {file name:filePath2} at after paragraph 5 of content
end tell
```

Comment: I have to support Arabic language (Right to Left align). So is there any possibility to align the content Right to Left  through Apple Script for New Mail screen? Thanks in advance.